# Remove duplicate rows from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem is:

```
select (..)
UNION 
select (..)
```

Result is:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3

 Val1    Text1  Data
 Val1    Text2  Data
```

The problem is that i need to save only 1 row of this two. Col2 value is not same at fact, but the same in business logic.

So, how to get result like this:

```
Col1, Col2,Col3
Val1  Text1 Data
```

OR

```
Col1, Col2, Col3
Val1  Text2 Data
```

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like what you want isn't a `UNION` but a `JOIN`. Maybe a `FULL OUTER JOIN`? `UNION` is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing here; return each distinct row. Those rows are distinctly different, so `UNION` returns both.

Comment: Add your sample data and your full query. If you did use Union, there should not be 2 same rows.

Comment: Which columns decide whether it's a duplicate or not?

Comment: @Charlieface, Col1 and Col3 , not Col2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can place the `UNION` in a subquery and group again**

```sql
SELECT
  Col1,
  MIN(Col2),
  Col3
FROM (
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM table1 t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM table2 t2
) t
GROUP BY
  Col1,
  Col2;
```

Note the use of `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`, because you are grouping anyway it is not necessary to de-duplicate first.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . If you want one row per val, then one method is:

```
with t1 as ( < query 1 here > ),
     t2 as ( < query 2 here > )
select t1.*
from t1
union all
select t2.*
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.val = t2.val);
```